# $U/U_3 \equiv (\mathbb{Z}/27\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, hensels-lemma

I was reading this: [What is the group structure of 3-adic group of the cubes of units?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263344/what-is-the-group-structure-of-3-adic-group-of-the-cubes-of-units), but I do not understand why $U/U_3 \equiv (\mathbb{Z}/27\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U=\Bbb Z_p^\times$, the group of units in the $p$-adic integers.
Let $U_k=\{u\in U: u\equiv1\pmod{p^k}\}$ for $k\in\Bbb N$.
Then $U/U_k\cong(\Bbb Z/p^k\Bbb Z)^\times$. The reason is that
mapping $u\in U$ to $u$ modulo $p^k$ is a surjective group
homomorphism to $(\Bbb Z/p^k\Bbb Z)^\times$ with kernel $U_k$.

Comment: Thank you @Lord Shark the Unknown