# order of $\mathbb{Z}_3^{\times}/(\mathbb{Z}_3^{\times})^3$

Tags: commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, quotient-group

Based on this: [What is the group structure of 3-adic group of the cubes of units?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263344/what-is-the-group-structure-of-3-adic-group-of-the-cubes-of-units), we know that $(\mathbb{Z}_3^{\times})^3$ are the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ that are congruent to $(+/-)1 \mod 9$. How can we know the order of $\mathbb{Z}_3^{\times}/(\mathbb{Z}_3^{\times})^3$? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, one has the explicit isomorphism $ \mathbf Z_p^{\times} \cong  \mathbf Z/(p-1) \mathbf Z \oplus \mathbf Z_p $ for odd $ p $. The subgroup $ (\mathbf Z_3^{\times})^3 $ corresponds under this isomorphism to the subgroup $ (3 \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z) \oplus 3 \mathbf Z_3 = \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z \oplus 3 \mathbf Z_3 $, so taking quotients yields $ (\mathbf Z_3^{\times})/(\mathbf Z_3^{\times})^3 \cong \mathbf Z_3/3 \mathbf Z_3 \cong \mathbf Z/3 \mathbf Z $.

Comment: Question @Starfall, in here, you never used the fact that $(\mathbb{Z}_3^{\times})^3$ are the elements in $\mathbb{Z}_3^{\times}$ congruent with $\pm1 (\mod 9)$, right?

Comment: @Gibson No, I haven't, although that follows easily if you explicitly write down the isomorphism.